# How to export base64 to file?

Tags: base64

I am currently trying to decode an image attachment from my e-mail (jpg) from base64 into unicode and then export it into a file (so I can get the image back from the raw data).

I now have the data decoded from base64 into Unicode, but how do I convert Unicode back to an image?

Hope you can help!

Comment: Base64 is usually used to convert binary data (like images) into text for safe transport through text-only systems (like email). I don't understand why there might be an intermediate unicode format involved. Please explain further.

Comment: Does `cat <the base64 file> | base64 --decode >image.jpg` not work? (Assuming linux)

Answer (score 17):

You don't have to convert it to unicode.

On a Linux box you can simply save the base64 decoded attachment to disk and do:

```
cat foo | base64 -d > bar.jpg
```

For windows you can download this tool:

http://www.f2ko.de/downloads/base64.zip

Comment: Running `base64 -d > bar.jpg <foo` avoids the needless `cat` invocation.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to decode several files from attachment you can use spesial online services like [Base64online.org/decode](http://base64online.org/decode). It can decode your base64 encoded data into downloadable image.