# Convert base64 encoded value to Hexadecimal in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an image stored in a table as a base64 encoded string. I have to convert it to a hexadecimal format and copy the value into another table. So i am looking for a way to do this in SQL

I tried it like this, but it did not work (I tested the result using an online converter)

```
select 
    cast(cast(@base64value as varchar(max)) as varbinary(max))
```

To clarify i want to convert base 64 to hexadecimal.

Comment: Do you want hex of the value or of the original binary?

Comment: If you want to get the file out of the database see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638245/how-to-export-base64-to-file

Comment: I want the hex of the value. Also i dont want to get the file out of the database. I have to convert it to hex and copy it into another table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Base64 encoding in SQL Server 2005 T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082345/base64-encoding-in-sql-server-2005-t-sql)

Comment: i figured it out: `CAST( @base64value as XML ).value('.','varbinary(max)')`